# Does absolute continuity of integral imply integrability on finite measure space.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Absolute continuity: For all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $\mu(A)<\delta$, $\int_{A}|f|d\mu<\epsilon$.  Here $A$ is a measurable subset of $E$.

I know that if $f$ is integrable then it is absolutely continuous. But is there anyway I can show that absolute continuity implies integrability when $\mu$ is finite?

$\int |f| d\mu=\int_A |f|d\mu+\int_{A^c} |f|d\mu$

Can I choose some special set $A$ such that $\mu(A)<\delta$?

Comment: Hint: think of some $A$ where $f$ is bounded, use continuity of measure.

Comment: Thanks but how do we know that such a set can exist?

Comment: Consider $A_M = \{ x \mid f(x) \leq M \}$. Now the union of all $A_M$ must have finite measure.

Comment: Just to remark, I'm assuming here that the function does not attain infinite values, that is $\lvert f(x) \rvert < \infty$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I think for $A_m$ you want $|f(x)|>M$ so that $lim A_m=0$. Also can we conclude that f is finite almost everywhere from absolute continuity or do we need to make that assumption.

Comment: Consider $f = \infty$ on $\mathbb{N}$ with weight on $0$ measure ($\mu (\{ 0 \}) = 1, \mu(\{n\}) = 0$ for $n \neq 0$). Then $\mu(A) < \delta = 1/2$ shows $A$ mustn't contain $\{0\}$, so it's a set of measure $0$, hence $\int_A \lvert f \rvert = 0$, but $\lvert f \rvert$ is clearly not integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be finite almost everywhere, say, in $E$. Then if $A_n = \{ x \mid \lvert f(x) \rvert \leq M \}$, we have $\bigcup^\infty_{n = 0} A_M = E$.

Since it is an increasing sequence of sets $A_M \uparrow E$ and the measure is finite, for any $\delta > 0$ we have $M$ such that $\mu(A_M) > \mu(E) - \delta$, so that $\mu(A_M^c) < \delta$. Now, if we choose $\delta$ so that $\mu(B) < \delta \implies \int_B \lvert f \rvert < 1$, we have

$$\int \lvert f \rvert = \int_E \lvert f \rvert = \int_{A_M} \lvert f \rvert + \int_{A_M^c} \lvert f \rvert \leq M \mu(A_M) + 1 < \infty.$$